# How to save the result of k fold for SVM in R

Tags: r, regression, svm

I have a SVM model using K-fold Cross-Validation and I want to save the result of each fold (cross-validation result and their corresponding actual and predicted values) in an array. Therefore, I have tried the following code but I am struggling with this error. I am not good in R. I would be thanks full if anyone can solve my problem with this loop.

Error:

> Error in `*tmp*`[[j]] : subscript out of bounds

My code is as follows:

**Edited**

```
#required Packages
library(rminer)
library("caret")
library("e1071")
#Generating random numbers
B1 <- c(runif(100))
B2 <- c(runif(100))
B3 <- c(runif(100))
AWC<-c(runif(100))#Target variable(respond)
data_scale<-data.frame(B1,B2,B3,AWC)


foldss<-createFolds(data_scale,,k=3)
#creating list and arry for storring the resuls for all folds.
value_svm<-list()
value_svm_all<-array()
cv_ksvm_result<-list()
cv_ksvm_total_result<-array()
#Construct the loop for all process
for(i in 1:3){
for(j in 1:3) {
#crearetest and trainset
dat_terain<-data_scale[(-foldss[[i]]),]
dat_test<-data_scale[foldss[[i]],]
#Build the model
fit_svm<-e1071::svm(AWC~.,data=dat_terain,kernel="radial")
#predict 
AWC_pred<-predict(fit_svm, dat_test)
print(value_svm[[j]])<-AWC_pred
value_svm_all<-cbind(value_svm_all,value_svm[[j]])

cv_ksvm_result[[i]]<- 
mmetric(dat_test$AWC,AWC_pred,c("MAE","RMSE","MAPE","RMSPE",

"RRSE","RAE","COR","R2"))
print(cv_ksvm_result[[i]])
cv_ksvm_total_result<-cbind(cv_ksvm_total_result, cv_ksvm_result[[i]])  
 }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us some data sample in order to reproduce the error

Comment: Dear @AdelmoFilho I have added some data to my code.

Answer (score 1):

The source of error is this chunk:

```
print(value_svm[[j]])<-AWC_pred
```

You just need to replace to:

```
value_svm[[j]]<-AWC_pred
```

But, in reality there´s another issues on this code.

When you set...

```
foldss<-createFolds(data_scale,,k=3)
```

... you are intent to have 3 folds, but it returns only 2. createFolds function expects a vector as first argument in order to get the dataframe´s number of rows. When a full dataset is provided it takes the number of columns.

I´ve made the necessary adjustments and now the code runs correctly

```
#required Packages
library(rminer)
library("caret")
library("e1071")
#Generating random numbers
B1 <- c(runif(100))
B2 <- c(runif(100))
B3 <- c(runif(100))
AWC<-c(runif(100))#Target variable(respond)
data_scale<-data.frame(B1,B2,B3,AWC)


foldss<-createFolds(data_scale$AWC,,k=3)
#creating list and arry for storring the resuls for all folds.
value_svm<-list()
value_svm_all<-array()
cv_ksvm_result<-list()
cv_ksvm_total_result<-array()
#Construct the loop for all process
for(i in 1:3){
    #crearetest and trainset
    dat_terain<-data_scale[(-foldss[[i]]),]
    dat_test<-data_scale[foldss[[i]],]
    #Build the model
    fit_svm<-e1071::svm(AWC~.,data=dat_terain,kernel="radial")
    #predict 
    AWC_pred<-predict(fit_svm, dat_test)
    value_svm[[i]]<-AWC_pred
    value_svm_all<-cbind(value_svm_all,value_svm[[i]])

    cv_ksvm_result[[i]]<- 
      mmetric(dat_test$AWC,AWC_pred,c("MAE","RMSE","MAPE","RMSPE",

                                      "RRSE","RAE","COR","R2"))
    print(cv_ksvm_result[[i]])
    cv_ksvm_total_result<-cbind(cv_ksvm_total_result, cv_ksvm_result[[i]])  
}
```